# How to avoid php getting vuejs params as string when it is undefined or null

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, parameters, url-parameters

That is maybe a dumb question or asked many times (if so, answer with existing link and I will close this post).

Let's say in laravel by example, when send model id in route, everything is ok in php. But when a route must optional parameter defined as null in Vuejs (or undefined), Php gets this parameter as string.

```
//vuejs in methods:
myFunction(id1, id2 = null) {
  axios.post(`/api/model1/${id1}/model2/${id2}`)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
 },
```

And

```
//Laravel routes/api.php for my api
Route::post('model1/{id}/model2/{id2}', 'SomeController@doThis');
```

> Example: myapi/model1/{id1}/model2/{id2} and
> myapi/model1/987/model2/null

So I get 'null' here for model2. (sometimes it is 'undefined' according to the situation)

What is the better way to deal with it?
without adding regex for my parameters? because I do not need regex for the first param what is id1.

I try to deal with it many times, but it seems I always come back to this problem from time to time. I need to keep this in my mind once for all.

Comment: This likely caused by the code that you use to generate the URLs to call. Can you share that code?

Answer (score 0):

You should do null checks when constructing the URL:

```js
//vuejs in methods:
myFunction(id1, id2 = null) {
  axios.post(`/api/model1/${id1}/model2${id2 ? `/${id2}` : ''}`)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
 },
```

You should also make the 2nd parameter optional:

```
Route::post('model1/{id}/model2/{id2?}', 'SomeController@doThis');
```

Answer (score 0):

How making the your laravel route parameter as an optional :
[Optional Parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

```
Route::post('model1/{id}/model2/{id2?}', 'SomeController@doThis');
```

add the `?` at the `model2` parameter.